# How to install jasmine-node on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, jasmine-node

I have successfully installed node.js(v0.6.12) and npm(v1.1.4). However when I try to install jasmine-node with the console command from the website(https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node);

```
npm install jasmine-node -g
```

I got the following error :

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node
npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: jasmine-node
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
...
...
```

I have tried lots of different versions like putting sudo in front of it, I tried the command without g, I tried "npm install jasmine-node@2.0.0 -g", I tried proxy..

However it didn't work. I couldn't find much on Google as well.

So How can I install jasmine-node on Ubuntu?

Comment: Definitely find a package for a version newer that `v0.6.12`. It is more than two years old, which is a long time for an application still under heavy development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to be a temporary issue on npm's side.  I just ran your command on Linux Mint (a derivative of Ubuntu) and it went fine.

I would recommend you get the latest version of Node from Chris Lea's ppa: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os